# How to import a module when deploying a Python App on Google Cloud?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, import, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a Python app to Google Cloud.

All my code is happening in *main.py* but it uses csv files from the folder */data* in the same project. It works locally in my virtualenvironment but when I try to deploy to gcloud, I can see in the log:

> import pandas as pd ImportError: No module named pandas

However I do have *pandas* in my *requirement.txt*

If of any help, this is what my project folder looks like:

```
/data
/env
/lib
/mypython
/static
/templates
app.yaml
appengine_config.py
main.py
requirements.txt
```

Comment: have you checked this doc https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27? Some python libraries cannot be used in google app engine due to the c extension and app engine's sandbox nature. I am not sure whether you can use pandas (i think so), maybe you have to use app engine flexible environment or other solutions.

Comment: Yes, I ran `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I noticed the question has python-3.x tag, what is the python version of your app engine environment. (I know the python 3 for app engine standard environment is beta or something),  you can check by go to https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?folder=&organizationId=&project=yourGoogleCloudProjectId

Comment: Can you indicate if you are in [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries) or [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies) environment?